# Command line to detect graphics card driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, graphic-card

Is there anyway to detect which driver is now handling the graphic card on my Ubuntu 18.04?
I have NVIDIA Geforce 740M on my laptop.

Comment: See also [How to inspect the currently used Nvidia driver version and switch it to another alternative?](https://askubuntu.com/q/670485/19753).

Answer (score 0):

You may execute `nvidia-smi | grep -i driver` and look for "Driver Version".

Or simply `nvidia-smi` should provide you that information inside a box.

Comment: I get the following result as the driver:
_| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |_
but in all info mode it show 0 GPUs:
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
How can I enable GPU?

Comment: Perhaps it's not selected and you're using the integrated one? Difficult to guess. That deserves another question if your own research fails to help.